# How to use JS to build a slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to finish my first website, I have short deadline, I know html css and a bit of JQuery, but right JS is still difficult for me

I would like to have a slideshow in my website, that's why I went to the w3school and tried to replicate the example in my visual studio code.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  var slideIndex = 1;
  showSlides(slideIndex);

  function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
  }

  function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("myslides");
    if (n > slides.length) {
      slideIndex = 1
    }
    if (n < 1) {
      slideIndex = slides.length
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";

    }

  });
```

```css
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.myslides {
  display: none;
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="myslides fade">
    <img src="./IMAGENS/CASA A (1).jpg" width="100%">
  </div>
  <div class="myslides fade">
    <img src="./IMAGENS/CASA B (3).jpg" width="100%">
  </div>
  <div class="myslides fade">
    <img src="./IMAGENS/MUDA_L11_02_FINAL.jpg" width="100%">
  </div>
  <div class="myslides fade">
    <img src="./IMAGENS/MUDA_L11_05_FINAL.jpg" width="100%">
  </div>
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

When I try to refresh the page everything looks fine but when I click in the button to change slides nothing happens. What you think should I do?

I tried to make a slideshow with arrays and it didn´t work. So I think it´s a problem with my VSCODE not assuming these two elements.

```
<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a> 
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
```

In my program when I do onclick="plusSlides(-1)" the first quote appears in yellow but the second one in white it seems that onclick is not asssigned

Comment: Do you get any error in console? Also your js is missing `})` at some point, please make your code complete. You can also replace your images with some [placeholders](https://loremipsum.io/21-of-the-best-placeholder-image-generators/)

Comment: Hi Barbsan

I´ve edit my post, now I have  })  there, simply forgot to put it here, thanks!

Yes I have a console error it says:
    Uncaught ReferenceError: plusSlides is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Comment: I don´t think so, I tried it and it didn´t work.
So I think it´s a problem with my VSCODE  not assuming these two elements.

                      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>

                      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

   In my program when I do onclick="plusSlides(-1)" the first quote appears in 
   yellow but the second one in white it seems that onclick is not asssigned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your functions are declared on [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) of `$(document).ready`'s callback, so `onclick` cannot reach them.

Solution 1: Move your declarations outside `$(document).ready`'s callback.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;

$(document).ready(() => {
  showSlides(slideIndex);
});


function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("myslides");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";

}
```

```css
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.myslides {
  display: none;
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="myslides fade">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200&text=image+1" width="100%">
  </div>
  <div class="myslides fade">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200&text=image+2" width="100%">
  </div>
  <div class="myslides fade">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200&text=image+3" width="100%">
  </div>
  <div class="myslides fade">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200&text=image+4" width="100%">
  </div>
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

Solution 2: Remove `onclick` attributes and add click listeners in `$(document).ready`'s callback

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  var slideIndex = 1;
  showSlides(slideIndex);

  $(".prev").click(function() {
    plusSlides(-1);
  });

  $(".next").click(function() {
    plusSlides(1);
  });

  function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
  }

  function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("myslides");
    if (n > slides.length) {
      slideIndex = 1
    }
    if (n < 1) {
      slideIndex = slides.length
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";

  }
});
```

```css
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.myslides {
  display: none;
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="myslides fade">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200&text=image+1" width="100%">
  </div>
  <div class="myslides fade">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200&text=image+2" width="100%">
  </div>
  <div class="myslides fade">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200&text=image+3" width="100%">
  </div>
  <div class="myslides fade">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200&text=image+4" width="100%">
  </div>
  <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect solution man!

Answer (score 2):

Just as @edinhajdarevic said, using an array is a better approach due to many advantages, some of those are the following:

1. Rendering your slides in the DOM using an array makes your structure dynamic. Dynamic means, everytime you want to add a new slide, you could append a new `slide` object to your array of slides, instead of writting an HTML and a JavaScript every slide by hand.
2. Once you have all of your slide code defined, you will be able to mantain your code with ease, instead of reading multiple lines, you just have to care about your JavaScript code.
3. Less error prone, every time you copy/paste HTML or JavaScript to build another slide, you will have to change values based on the new slide, sometimes this turns into a messy work causing bugs in a future.

A nice tutorial can be found in the following W3Schools link:

[Slideshow Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp)